# Get string from url example: domain.com/THESTRING

Tags: php, string, parsing, url

Please some one explain to me how it works and how to do it.

Comment: Asaf, please use the search function before posting a question.

Comment: Please give us a better explanation of what you mean.

Comment: Google (or search here) for "how to use PHP with mod_rewrite" or "php mod_rewrite tutorial".

Comment: If you have found an solution to your question, please don't add it to your question; scroll to the bottom here and submit it as an answer.  You will be able to select it as correct after the requisite waiting period and close this question out.

Answer (score 3):

PHP has a function just for this: [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

```
$parts = parse_url('domain.com/THESTRING');
$path = $parts['path'];
```

That wil get the part that you want

Comment: But when i enter to a page like that the server (localhost) tell me that the page isn't found, what should I do?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, the `parse_url` function just splits the parts of a URL up like you ask in your question

Comment: Yes it's split fine, but I can't access to a page like domain.com/blabla cuz isn't really exist on the server.

Comment: @Asaf: I think it might be best to open a new question for this new problem, people won't find it if it's buried in the comments here.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way:

```
echo strstr(str_replace('://', '', 'domain.com/THESTRING'), '/'); // THESTRING
```

EDIT: [This](http://www.sitepoint.com/article/guide-url-rewriting/) should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Could also use below if you want the current URI:

```
$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Make sure your server support Mod_Rewrite**
I opened a .htaccess in the public_html directory.
Then turned on the Mod_Rewrite by this command:

```
RewriteEngine on
```

Then I write a new law:

```
RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ index.php?link=$1
```

Thats bicycly mean that every url that ends with .html will redirect to index.php
Then in index.php I get the URL link